# Lesson 19 Project - Two Orders For Price of One - Sorting Arrays

Tags: java

I am using the Blue Pelican Java textbook and am stuck on the project for Lesson 19. It asks to:
Modify the code below to print two side-by-side columns. The first column should be in ascending order (like the code below will print), and the second column should be in descending order. The output should be:

```
Ascend   Descend
Agnes    Thomas
Alfred   Mary
Alvin    Lee
Bernard  Herman
Bill     Ezra
Ezra     Bill
Herman   Bernard
Lee      Alvin
Mary     Alfred
Thomas   Agnes
```

The code currently is:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Tester
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String ss[] = {"Bill", "Mary", "Lee", "Agnes", "Alfred", "Thomas", "Alvin", "Bernard", "Ezra", "Herman"};
        Arrays.sort(ss);
        for(String varSs: ss)
            System.out.println(varSs);
    }
}
```

How do I make the Descending column?
Thanks, -AJ

Comment: "oh right. thanks! problem solved – Alex G Aug 31 at 4:20" for instance, so hit the tick next to the score for the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
Arrays.sort(ss, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

import java.util.Collections which you've already imported includes the reverseOrder method which will sort in descending order.

Comment: This will work. I wonder why the `Comparator` is returned with a method rather than being a static field, like many things in Java?

Comment: @ChrisDennett - It's because the method is generic, letting you use type inference.

Comment: Oh right, I was looking at the 1.4.2 docs. They put the method in then added the generics later ;) Very clever.

Comment: @ChrisDennett - Oh you're right, that was rather precog of them :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint for you: look at [`Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29), as well as the [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Collections.reverse()` method.

```
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(ss));
```

Answer (score 0):

Write you own `Comparator` and use this interface:

```
Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

You can even do reverse iteration to you array from the end.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go against the grain and recommend that you sort only once just as you're doing. Then use a for loop, not a for-each loop, and use the for loop index to get the String for the first column, and the array index, the length of the array and just very simple math to get the index of the String for the second column. Then line the two Strings up using System.out.printf(...).  This is much easier than sorting the array twice once in reverse order (or using a Comparator -- gross overkill if you ask me).

Answer (score -1):

I suspect they're looking for something like the following:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Tester
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String ss[] = {"Bill", "Mary", "Lee", "Agnes", "Alfred", "Thomas", "Alvin", "Bernard", "Ezra", "Herman"};
        Arrays.sort(ss);
        int length = ss.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < length ; i++)
            System.out.println(ss[i]+"\t"+ss[length-1-i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice job of spoon-feeding him the solution there big guy. Great way to encourage him to learn to think.

Comment: Edit: Good thing you've made a mistake in there that the OP will have to fix if he's to turn this in.

Comment: either chip edited it, or it worked all along. this code runs fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
String [] ss = {"Bill", "Mary", "Lee", "Agnes", "Alfred", "Thomas", "Alvin","Bernard", "Ezra", "Herman"};

Arrays.sort(ss);
System.out.println("Ascend" + "   " +"Descend");
System.out.println();
for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(ss[i] + "    "+ ss[ss.length-(i+1)]);
}
```

Comment: whats the problem in my answer ? @Misa Lazovic

Comment: If you're asking me why I edited it: just look at edit history and tell me it doesn't look better this way. You left a placeholder value for a code snippet and missed he indentation on the rest of the code, so I had to edit it.  
However, if you are pinging me because of your down vote, I didn't give it. Still, since you asked, here are my 2 cents: the answer would be much better if you left some explanation besides the code.

Comment: thank you Misa Lazovic. Actually i am new in stackoverflow. So i dont know how to answer the questions thank you for your advice next time i wont do this type of mistake @Misa Lazovic